# How to pass a JavaScript array to C# function using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have array of strings in JavaScript passed on the button click, here on button click the dataArray stores string value of first elements from the table in which some of the rows has been selected after that i `stringify` as JSON and call a Ajax function to send the data to my code behind function DeleteStudent.
my JavaScript function that i call on button click:

```
$('#deleteStudent').click(function () {
            var dataArr = [];
            $.each($("#StudentTable tr.selected"), function () {
                dataArr.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()); 
            });
            var StudentList = JSON.stringify(dataArr);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ViewStudents.aspx/DeleteStudent",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { Students: dataArr },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Yay! It worked!');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Oh no :(  : '+result);
                }
            });
            console.log(StudentList);
    });
```

the dataArray looks like this

```
["10363","10364","10366"]
```

the  code behind function:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DeleteStudent(string[] Students)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reached CS");
    string[] a =Students;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        string admissionNumber=a[i];
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand deleteStudent = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                deleteStudent.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                deleteStudent.Connection = conn;
                deleteStudent.CommandText = "DELETE FROM validstudents WHERE admissionNumber = @admissionNumber ";

                deleteStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admissionNumber", admissionNumber);

                conn.Open();
                deleteStudent.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it gives a 500 internal server

Comment: Set `traditional: true` in your ajax request options.

Comment: not working added that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always stringify JSON before sending it to a `WebMethod`

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Students: dataArr })
```

Comment: thanks alot :) was using stringify but didn't send it to the ajax function

Answer (score 1):

This will work(In javascript)

```
       var optionSelected ="me"
                    var id = { id: optionSelected };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetConnectionProvider", "Customers")',
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(id),
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(datas) {


                        }
                    });
In Action

 public ActionResult GetConnectionProvider(int id)
{
   //write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by   `List<string> data`

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DeleteStudent(string[] data)
{
```

else

```
 [WebMethod]
public static void DeleteStudent(List<string> data)
{   

   data: { data : dataArr },
```